# Why does my web page render differently coming from my web server vs VS2010's web server?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, css, internet-explorer, iis-7

[image]

I am using IE11 on Widnows 7. The server is 2008, IIS v7.0.6...

As you can see by the picture the dropshadow doesn't show up on the banner and the border on the calendar is not as dark.

Same code, same browser, different server.

Any suggestions as to what causes this and how I can fix it?

Any ideas on where to look?

Comment: Check compatibility mode.

Comment: You are correct. At first I didn't see my server in the list then I noticed 'Display intranet sites in Compatibility view' was checked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this tag in the head section of your file

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

maybe the browser is rendering you page with a lower version than it has, this forces to IE to render the page with the last version posible

Also after adding that press `ctrl` + `F5` in the browser to request all from server and no from cache

Comment: 'Display intranet sites in Compatibility view' was checked. I assume LOCALHOST is not within the intranet. I am sure this is set by our IT department and if I change it they change it back on the next reboot as they do my home page and whatnot. Thanks for advice, it has been added to all my master pages.

Comment: Where did you find the 'Display intranet sites in Compatibility view' porperty/option? I didn't know about that

Comment: Under the Tools menu, 'Compatibility View Settings', bottom there are two checkboxes one has this caption.